# How to find the length of a side in a right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

If the length of a side in a right triangle is 8 and the hypothenuse is $\sqrt{113}$, what is the length of the other side ?

I tried different formulas but I'm not getting any answer.

Answer choices -

A. 7

B. 9

C. $\sqrt{177}$

D. 19

Comment: "if the length of one right  triangle" presumably means "if the length of one of the shorter sides of a right triangle."

Comment: Have you heard about Pythagoras ?

Comment: I suggest you use the formula that links together hypothenuse and catheti. The ones that do not do that would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. We are looking for a *positive* number $a$ such that
$$
a^2+8^2=113
$$$$
a^2=49.
$$

Comment: It isn't a hint it is an answer

Comment: To me, an answer would *at least* says where $a^2+8^2=113$ comes from... and it would give the choice to make between A, B, C and D.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the Pythagorean theorem.
>
> It states that the square of the hypotenuse (the side opposite the right angle) is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides. The theorem can be written as an equation relating the lengths of the sides a, b and c, often called the "Pythagorean equation":
>
> $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
>
> In a picture, it looks like:
>
> [image]

So, in your example:

$$a^2+8^2=\left(\sqrt{113}\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow a^2+64=113\Longleftrightarrow a=\pm\sqrt{113-65}=\pm7$$

But, in a triangle $a$ can only be positive, so $a=7$.